# Vuetify doesn't activate its components

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

```
vue@2.6.10
vuetify@2.2.25
```

I have the following code.

**Plugin of Vuetify**:

```
$ cat src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    dark: false
  }
});
```

**Import and activate it**:

```
$ cat src/main.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

<some irrelevant code and imports reducted>

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**Root App HTML code** (irrelevant code reducted):

```
$ cat src/App.vue

<template lang="pug">
  #app
    component(:is="layout")
      router-view /
</template>
```

And finally I use it in **one of pages**:

```
$ cat src/layouts/PrivateLayout.vue

<template lang="pug">
div
    v-app
        ...
        router-view
</template>
```

And this is what I see in the console of DevTools:

```
Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly?
```

Does anybody have an idea what happens? I've read already all the similar question (there are tons) but none of the answers helped.

---

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @morphatic the solution was either:

- Import every element manually
- or install package that imports everything automaticallty: **npm install --save vuetify-loader**

Second way, obviously will increase the size as you import redundant things. But it's easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sneaky one! Your project structure looks correct to me. The only part that is different from most of the Vuetify apps I've seen is this part:

```html
<template lang="pug">
  #app
    component(:is="layout")
      router-view /
</template>
```

Even though you appear to have registered all of the Vuetify components globally, when you use dynamic components (`<component :is="layout">`), my guess is that the build system is doing some sort of lazy loading or late binding which causes `<v-app>` not to be loaded in time to be recognized. [This is mentioned as a special case in the Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte/#dynamic-components).

I think there are a couple of things you can try:

1. Don't load your layout with a dynamic component
2. Explicitly import `VApp` to make sure it's there before you need it

I'm sorry I can't be more specific as I haven't solved this particular problem before, but I'm pretty sure that's what's causing it.

Comment: Yes. You gave the correct answer. Now it works. Vuetify checks if npm-package "vuetify-loader" is installed. If not - you have to load every single element manually. Thank you!!!
Please place about "vuetify-loader" in your answer so other people could find it faster.